# How to override parameter after magic setter and getter in php

Tags: php, getter-setter, magic-methods, mapper

Right now I have a BaseObject which do ORM to DB. I rely on private $data and magic setter and getter to create object with bunch of column as private object member(dynamically). Within child class, if i want to change behavior to set an individual object member I have to overide parent setter and look for the key. My question is if there is a better way to do this where I could just override single object member rather go through __setter

Base Object Mapper which map to db and dynamically create bunch of private params

```
class Base
 {
    private $data = array();

    public function __construct(){
        //get columns info from db and do set
    }
    public function __set($key, $value){
        $this->data[$key] = $value;        
    }

   public function __get($key){
       return isset($this->data[$key])? $this->data[$key] : null;       
   }
}
```

and child class.  Right now to override parameter setting I have to do this

```
 class Child extends Base
 {
     public function __set($name, $value){
        if($name == 'dog' && $value == 'chihuahua')
          $this->dog = 'dog bark wolf wolf';
        else if($name == 'cat' && $value == 'sand')
          $this->cat = 'cat say meow meow';
       ...
     }
 }
```

my question is there elegant way to do this, perhaps something like this in child class?

```
public function __set_dog($value)
    $this->dog = 'dog bark wolf wolf';

public function __set_cat($value)
   $this->cat = 'cat say meow meow';
```

the goal is to do

```
$animal1 = new Animal();
$anmial1->dog = 'pit bull';
$anmial1->cat= 'sand';

$animal2 = new Animal();
$anmial1->dog = 'chihuahua';
$anmial1->cat= 'house cat';
```

Comment: Could you spend a little more text on what you are trying to achieve? I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Right now I have a BaseObject which do ORM to DB.  I rely on private $data and magic setter and getter to create object with bunch of column as private object member(dynamically).  Within child class, if i want to change behavior to set an individual object member I have to overide parent setter and look for the key.  My question is if there is a better way to do this where I could just override single object member rather go through __setter.  Thanks in advance

Comment: If the object member is private, no, there's nothing else you can do.

Comment: Your `if()` statements are using `=` when you very likely mean `==`.

Comment: nickb thanks for catching that, I am just writting sudo code so yah.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can dynamically check if a conventionally named getter/setter method exists and call it instead of returning the $data member. Here's an example:

```
class Base {
    public function __get($key) {
        if (method_exists($this, $method = 'get' . ucfirst($key))) {
           return $this->$method($key);
        } else {
           return isset($this->data[$key])? $this->data[$key] : null;
        }
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        if (method_exists($this, $method = 'set' . ucfirst($key))) {
           $this->$method($key, $value);
        } else {
           $this->data[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}

class Animal extends Base {
    protected $data = array('fish' => 'blublublub', 'dog' => 'woof', 'cat' => 'meow');

    public function getDog() {
        return 'dog bark wolf wolf';
    }

    public function getCat() {
        return 'cat say meow meow';
    }
}

$animal = new Animal();
echo $animal->fish; // "blublublub"
echo $animal->dog; // "dog bark wolf wolf"
echo $animal->cat; // "cat say meow meow"
```